# Write utf-8 to a sql server Text field using ADO.Net and maintain the UTF-8 bytes

Tags: c#, sql-server, utf-8, sqlcommand

I have some xml encoded as UTF-8 and I want to write this to a Text field in SQL Server. UTF-8 is byte compatible with Text so it should be able to do this and then read out the xml later still encoded as utf-8.

However special characters such as ÄÅÖ, which are multi-byte in UTF-8 get changed on the way.

I have code like this:

```
byte[] myXML = ...

SqlCommand _MyCommand = new SqlCommand(storeProcedureName, pmiDB.GetADOConnection());
_MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
_MyCommand.Parameters.Add("xmlText", SqlDbType.Text);
_MyCommand.Parameters["xmlText"].Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myXML);
_MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My guess is that changing the xml byte array to string changes the special characters to UTF-16 characters which are then changed again to the Latin1. And Latin1 ÖÄÅ are not the same as UTF-8 ÖÄÅ.

How can I write the UTF-8 xml bytes to the Text field without them getting changed?

Comment: Have you encountered this article yet?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580

Comment: Thanks Mike, unfortuantely it seems to mostly say don't store it as UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that I got to work was to change the Stored Procedure so that the myXml parameter was Varbinary(Max), which allowed me to pass in the byte array. Then in the SP I Cast the Varbinary(max) to Varchar(max). This preserves the bytes as required for UTF-8

```
SET myXMLText = CAST(myXMLBinary as VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Answer (score 3):

Define your column as NText or NVarchar

Comment: The db table is already defined and in use so I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store UTF-8 use binary then, because text is stored internally as UTF-16

Comment: I think it's just NText that stores characters as UCS-2. Text stores the characters as single bytes

Answer (score 0):

If it's XML and if you're on SQL Server 2005 and up - use the XML column type! It's faster, it's more compact than VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX), you can associate it with an XML schema and thus validate only valid XML is stored.... only benefits!

If you can't use the XML column type for whatever reason, then *please* at least drop the TEXT for VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX)! TEXT/NTEXT is deprecated and will go away - plus, with (N)VARCHAR(MAX), you get all the usual strings functions, too, that don't work on TEXT/NTEXT.

Comment: I would love to use the xml type but unfortunately we need the ability to store data in all formats. Varbinary would have been best...