# SQL error on inserting UTF8 string into SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server, delphi, utf-8

I'm having problems trying to insert strings containing UTF-8 encoded Chinese characters and punctuations into a SQL Server 2008 table (default installation) from my Delphi 7 application using Zeosdb native SQL Server library.

I remembered in the past I had problems inserting UTF8 string into SQL Server even using PHP and other methods so I believe that this problem is not unique to Zeosdb.

It doesn't happen all the time, some UTF8 encoded strings can get inserted successfully but some not. I can't figure out what is it in the string that caused the failure.

**Table schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[incominglog](
    [number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [keyword] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [message] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [messagepart1] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [datetime] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [recipient] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**SQL statement template:**

```
INSERT INTO INCOMINGLOG ([Number], [Keyword], [Message], [MessagePart1], [Datetime], [Recipient]) 
VALUES('{N}', '{KEYWORD}', '{M}', '{M1}', '{TIMESTAMP}', '{NAME}')
```

The parameter `{KEYWORD}`, `{M}` and `{M1}` can contain UTF8 string.

For example, the following statement will return an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'é¢'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'å…¨åŠ›å…‹æœå››ç§å±é™©','2013-06-19 17:07:28','')'.

```
INSERT INTO INCOMINGLOG ([Number], [Keyword], [Message], [MessagePart1], [Datetime], [Recipient]) 
VALUES('+6590621005', 'é¢˜', 'é¢˜ [å…¨åŠ›å…‹æœå››ç§å±é™© åšå†³æ‰«é™¤ä½œé£Žä¹‹å¼Š]', '[å…¨åŠ›å…‹æœå››ç§å±é™©','2013-06-19 17:07:28', '')
```

Note: Please ignore the actual characters as the utf8 encoding is lost after copy and paste.

I've also tried using `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[incominglog](
    [number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [keyword] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [messagepart1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [datetime] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [recipient] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And also tried amending the SQL statement into:

```
INSERT INTO INCOMINGLOG ([Number],[Keyword],[Message],[MessagePart1],[Datetime],[Recipient]) VALUES('{N}',N'{KEYWORD}',N'{M}',N'{M1}','{TIMESTAMP}','{NAME}')
```

They don't work either.  I would appreciate any pointer.  Thanks.

> **EDITED:** As indicated by marc_s below, the N prefix must be outside the single quotes. It is correct in my actual test, the initial statement is a typo, which I've corrected.

The test with the N prefix also returned an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'åŽŸæ ‡é¢'. Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string 'å…¨åŠ›å…‹æœ?å››ç§?å?±é™©','2013-06-19
>   21:22:08','')'.

The SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO INCOMINGLOG ([Number],[Keyword],[Message],[MessagePart1],[Datetime],[Recipient]) VALUES('+6590621005',N'åŽŸæ ‡é¢˜',N'åŽŸæ ‡é¢˜ [å…¨åŠ›å…‹æœ?å››ç§?å?±é™© å?šå†³æ‰«é™¤ä½œé£Žä¹‹å¼Š]',N'[å…¨åŠ›å…‹æœ?å››ç§?å?±é™©','2013-06-19','')
```

.
.

> **REPLY TO gbn's Answer:** I've tried using parameterized SQL but still encountering "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string" error.

For the new test, I used a simplified SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO INCOMINGLOG ([Keyword],[Message]) VALUES(:KEYWORD,:M)
```

The error returned for the above statement:

> Incorrect syntax near 'åŽŸæ ‡é¢'. Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string '')'.

For info, the values of KEYWORD and M are:

> KEYWORD:åŽŸæ ‡é¢˜
>
> M:åŽŸæ ‡é¢˜ [

.
.
.

> **Further tests on 20th June** Parametarized SQL query don't work so I tried a different approach by trying to isolate the character that caused the error.  After trial and error, I managed to identify the problematic character.

The following character produces an error: é¢˜

SQL Statement: `INSERT INTO INCOMINGLOG ([Keyword]) VALUES('é¢˜')`

Interestingly, note that the string in the return error tax contains a "?" character which didn't exist in the original statement.

> Error: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'é¢?)'. Incorrect syntax near 'é¢?)'.

If I were to place some latin characters immediately after the culprit character, there will be no error.  For example, `INSERT INTO INCOMINGLOG ([Keyword]) VALUES('é¢˜Ok')` works ok.  Note: It doesn't work with all characters.

Comment: Does the UTF-8 string which you use as replacement for `{KEYWORD}` contain a quotation mark? The error message seems to indicate this. I recommend to use a parametrized query where such errors can not happen.

Comment: Parametrized queries will also prevent SQL injection.

Comment: hi mjn, I've doubled up all quotes. I suspect that quotes might not be the only illegal characters in UTF8 string.

Comment: Your SQL `INSERT INTO INCOMINGLOG ([Keyword]) VALUES('é¢˜')` works for me in SSMS

Comment: @gbn I'm not sure but I think it's not the same when you copy to SSMS, perhaps the encoding changes. The only way to test is using code - I've created PHP code that you can download from [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/ICYYU57A/sqlinserttest.html). There are 2 PHP files, one with the statement that works and another which fails.  By the way, this article says that MSSQL doesn't support UTF-8 - [article link](http://codex.galleryproject.org/Gallery2:MSSQL). Previously, before using UTF-8, I converted the UTF-8 to widestring, but they appear as question marks when viewed from SSMS.

Answer (score 3):

There are `'` characters in the UTF-8 which abnormally terminate the SQL.

Classic SQL injection.

Use proper parametrisation, not string concatenation basically.

Edit, after Question updates...

Without the Delphi code, I don't think we can help you
All SQL side code works. For example, this works in SSMS

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([Keyword] nvarchar(100) COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS);
INSERT INTO @t ([Keyword]) VALUES('é¢˜');
INSERT INTO @t ([Keyword]) VALUES(N'é¢˜');
SELECT * FROM @t T;
```

Something is missing to help us fic this

Also see

- [How to store UTF-8 bytes from a C# String in a SQL Server 2000 TEXT column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982499/how-to-store-utf-8-bytes-from-a-c-sharp-string-in-a-sql-server-2000-text-column)
- [Having trouble with UTF-8 storing in NVarChar in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723238/having-trouble-with-utf-8-storing-in-nvarchar-in-sql-server-2008)
- [Write utf-8 to a sql server Text field using ADO.Net and maintain the UTF-8 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883308/write-utf-8-to-a-sql-server-text-field-using-ado-net-and-maintain-the-utf-8-byte)

Comment: Thanks gbn, I've tried using parameterized SQL, but still the same error, please check my comment in the original question.

Comment: I like point out that my SQL Server db is using Chinese_PRC_CI_AS collation.  I've no issues inserting the same data in GBK encoding manually using SQL management studio - but my software inserts using UTF8.

Comment: @Joshua: Can you add the Delphi code please. This could be a client error, not a SQL error as such

Comment: I've created another question for this, from where there's a link which you can download a test program I made - click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230419/unable-to-insert-unicode-into-mssql-2008-using-delphi-zeoslib-and-delphi-7).  To reproduce the problem, uncomment "//inserted as utf8" and remove the "ok" in the editbox.