# Unable to insert Unicode into SQL Server 2008 using Delphi ZeosLib and Delphi 7

Tags: sql-server, delphi, zeos

I'm having trouble inserting Unicode into a SQL Server database using Delphi ZeosLib and Delphi 7, and then reading the inserted value. I've created a simple test program that first inserts and then queries the inserted value.

The test table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[incominglog](
    [message] [nvarchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I've upload the simple test program source (ZeosLib source included) - [click here](http://www.2shared.com/file/jwyx79eE/testdb.html) to download. I've also included ntwdblib.dll but you can use your own.

The test program also requires TNT component which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.axolot.com/TNT/)

Using the test program, the Unicode characters that I have inserted appear as question marks on retrieval - I'm not certain whether the problem lies with the insert code or the query code.

I've also tried encoding the data into utf-8 before inserting and then decoding the data after retrieving from utf-8 - please search "//inserted as utf8" in the test program source. I'm able to view the Unicode after it has been decoded, so this method works.  However, for my actual application, I can't encode as UTF-8 as SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8 completely - some characters can't be stored. See my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189288/sql-error-on-inserting-utf8-string-into-sql-server-2008-table).

Will appreciate any pointers. :)

Meanwhile, here's the source for the Test program:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  ZConnection, Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ZAbstractRODataset, ZAbstractDataset, ZAbstractTable, ZDataset,
  StdCtrls, TntStdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    TntMemo1: TTntMemo;
    Button2: TButton;
    TntEdit1: TTntEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  FZConnection: TZConnection;
  FZQuery: TZQuery;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tntmemo1.Lines.Clear;
  FZConnection := TZConnection.Create(Owner);
  FZConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
  FZQuery := TZQuery.Create(Owner);
  FZQuery.Connection := FZConnection;
  FZConnection.Protocol := 'mssql';
  FZConnection.Database := 'replace-with-your-db';
  FZConnection.HostName := 'localhost';
  FZConnection.User := 'sa';
  FZConnection.Password := 'replace-with-your-password';
  FZConnection.Connect;
  FZQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * from incominglog';
  FZQuery.ExecSQL;
  FZQuery.Open;
  FZQuery.First;
  while not FZQuery.EOF do
  begin
   tntmemo1.Lines.add(FZQuery.FieldByName('message').AsString);
  // tntmemo1.Lines.add(utf8decode(FZQuery.FieldByName('message').AsString));  //inserted as utf8
    FZQuery.Next;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
sqlstring, data:widestring;
begin
  FZConnection := TZConnection.Create(Owner);
  FZConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
  FZQuery := TZQuery.Create(Owner);
  FZQuery.Connection := FZConnection;
  FZConnection.Protocol := 'mssql';
  FZConnection.Database := 'replace-with-your-db';
  FZConnection.HostName := 'localhost';
  FZConnection.User := 'sa';
  FZConnection.Password := 'replace-with-your-password';
  FZConnection.Connect;
  data:= tntedit1.Text;
 // data:= utf8encode(tntedit1.Text);  //inserted as utf8
  sqlstring:= 'INSERT INTO INCOMINGLOG ([MESSAGE]) VALUES(N''' + data + ''')';
  FZQuery.SQL.Text := sqlstring;
  FZQuery.ExecSQL;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I don't know Zeos but using Delphi 7 I would expect the Text property of FZQuery.SQL being AnsiString.

Comment: I tried 'FZQuery.SQL.add(sqlstring);' the result is the same.

Comment: did you try it with a persisitand field ftWideString or parameters of type TWideString? As mentioned I don't know Zeos, sorry

Comment: @bummi Hi Bummi, I just found out that Zeos don't support widestrings so this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested your example, but I'm able to save and retrieve from database Unicode characters without problem on SQL Server with Delphi 7 VCL/CLX and zeoslib.

I think in your case it will be enough changing your save procedure like this :

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
sqlstring : widestring;
data : UTF8String;
begin
  FZConnection := TZConnection.Create(Owner);
  FZConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
  FZQuery := TZQuery.Create(Owner);
  FZQuery.Connection := FZConnection;
  FZConnection.Protocol := 'mssql';
  FZConnection.Database := 'replace-with-your-db';
  FZConnection.HostName := 'localhost';
  FZConnection.User := 'sa';
  FZConnection.Password := 'replace-with-your-password';
  FZConnection.Connect;
  data:= UTF8String( utf8encode(tntedit1.Text) );
  sqlstring:= 'INSERT INTO INCOMINGLOG ([MESSAGE]) VALUES(:DATA)';
  FZQuery.SQL.Text := sqlstring;
  FZQuery.ParamByName('DATA').AsString := data;
  FZQuery.ExecSQL;
end;
```

The point is changing your data string variable in UTF8String type, and use parameters pass the data string to the query ...
To be honest I use it with a ZTable and Post command, but it should be the same with a ZQuery like yours ...

Comment: It is the only way to go .